# Run scrapy in the python shell

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, scrapy

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed scrapy like this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy-0.24
```

If I write in the terminal:

```
scrapy
```

I got:

```
Scrapy 0.24.5 - project: ...
```

But if I run the python shell and write

```
import scrapy
```

I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named scrapy
```

What's wrong? I tried to re-install scrapy, but it didn't help.

Comment: The package you need is `python-scrapy`, from where did you get that `scrapy-0.24`?

Comment: I got scrapy from here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html. Why do I need python-scrapy?  For example https://github.com/scrapinghub/testspiders/blob/master/testspiders/spiders/followall.py it just import scrapy in the python module

Comment: `python-scrapy` is the name of the package in Ubuntu repository.

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html - Don’t use the python-scrapy package provided by Ubuntu, they are typically too old and slow to catch up with latest Scrapy.

Comment: The point is that `scrapy-0.24` was not in the main repo, so I wanted to know were you got it from.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Install `pip` (instructions abound) and then do `sudo pip install scrapy`

Comment: I did sudo apt-get purge scrapy-0.24., and sudo ap-get autoremove, and sudo apt-get autoclean then I did sudo pip install scrapy. After this I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I completely remove scrapy and then install it from a source - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Scrapy

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.24.5.tar.gz#md5=23e80a40e4c282e06ef3cdc88e97ffb2

tar -zxvf Scrapy-0.24.5.tar.gz

cd Scrapy-0.24.5

sudo python setup.py install
```

Maybe it would be helpful for somebody.

For Stefano Sanfilippo:

> If you don't know the answer it's better to keep silent and not to minus. It doesn't matter for installation what you install python-scrapy or scrapy-0.24, but python-scrapy from a repository is much more older and slower.

It's a bug in the Ubuntu 14.04 or in the pip. In the Ubuntu 12.04 everything works. If I install some software via pip, the path isn't found, but if I install it manually, everything works. When I installed django, I had the same issue.